# Rabbitmq connection issue when using a username and password

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to start some background processing through rabbitmq, but when I send the request, I get the below error in the rabbitmq log. But, I think I am providing the right credentials, as my celery works are able to connect to rabbitmq server using the same username/password combination.

> ```
> =ERROR REPORT==== 12-Jun-2012::20:50:29 ===
> exception on TCP connection  from 127.0.0.1:41708
> {channel0_error,starting,
>                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
>                             "AMQPLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials",
>                             'connection.start_ok'}}
> ```

Comment: The problem has been resolved, my application server was not using the celery configuration which is present in the ini file

Answer (score 0):

To get resolve connection with rabbitmq need to inspect below points:

- Connectivity from client machine to rabbitmq server machine [in case if client and server are running on separate machine], need to check
  along with port as well.
- Credential (username and password), a user must be onboarded into RabbitMQ which will be used to connect with RabbitMQ
- Permission to User must be given (permission may be attached to VHOST as well so need to provide permission carefully)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to debug permissions issues in the amqp protocol is to look at the request:

```
transport://userid:password@hostname:port/virtual_host
```

from http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#conf-broker-settings